# Events mutually independent - how to find the P?

Tags: independence

Let events $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ be  three mutually independent  events such that $P(A_j)$ = $(0.5)^j$ for $j=1,2,3$.

How to find the $P((A_1 \cup A_2) - A_3)$?

Comment: Did you mean to say $[P(A_1 \cup A_2)-P(A_3)]$?

Comment: @Aniket, you are right. I have just edited the $A_3$. Thanks

Comment: @Ganjira if you mean by the  - set  minus   , then check the edit .

Comment: @Nizar, I don't mean the - set minus.

Comment: @Ganjira so this minus refers to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(A_1\cup A_2)-P(A_3)=P(A_1)+P(A_2)-P(A_1\cap A_2)-P(A_3)$$ $$=P(A_1)+P(A_2)-P(A_1)\cdot P(A_2)-P(A_3)$$ since the events are independent $$=(0.5)^1+(0.5)^2-(0.5)^1 \cdot (0.5)^2+(0.5)^3$$ $$=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}$$ $$=\frac{3}{4}$$ $$$$